# Strings that aren't case-sensitive

Tags: c++, arrays, string

So, I want to create a chatbot in C++ and I declared an array of strings.

```
string hello_message[5] = {"hello", "hi", "good morning", "good afternoon", "good evening"};
```

Now, here is the problem. If the user types in "hello", the program will answer back but if the word he used is "Hello", the program doesn't recognize it in the string array.
How can I "negate" the case-sensivity of these strings?

Comment: Presumably you're doing a comparison of strings somewhere.  Either do a case-insensitive comparison or - since your array is all lower case - transform the other string to lower case before doing the comparison.

Comment: One of the few good things about raw arrays is that the compiler counts the elements for you. By explicitly writing `[5]`, you defeat that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Convert all the strings characters to lower case using [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and [std::tolower](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter string: ";
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::tolower);
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Use accordingly. Note that this will fail if you have multi-byte characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store all lowercase strings in the array of words 
and then you need to convert your input to lower case and check within the array.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 

std::string data = "Abc"; 
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to overcome this problem would be to convert all the input the user provides to lowercase, assuming this doesn't matter for the internals of your program. You could achieve this using tolower in the locale library.

See here for an example:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/tolower/

You could also store the original input if you wanted to output it again.

Answer (score 0):

if the user enters the data that does not match the words you have stored in your string it will definitely lead to some unplanned situation.
In this case you can either provide every possible user input into the array(which is a lot tedious)  or you can just use the transform every alphabet that user has given to lower,uppercase.

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
cout <<"say hi"<<endl;//if user enter "hi"
string str;
getline(std::cin, str);
transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(),::tolower);
cout << str;//it will be converted into "HI"
}
```

to uppercase a word replace tolower with toupper